# Which pronoun shall be used for nothing in the sentence: it or they/them

Tags: word-usage, pronouns

I wonder which pronoun this sentence takes.

> Nothing belongs to you on the planet, but you can make use of ***it/them.***

Answer (score 2):

*Nothing* is comprised of *no* and *thing.* Just like 'another' that is 'an other' something. **Broadly** they are singular. That's why we say - *Nothing **is** permanent.*

So, in the given sentence, it smoothly goes with *it.*

But note that you can write it in better way. Also, it'd avoid the complexity.

> You own nothing on this earth, but you can use everything.